# Where is WebDriver's Python API Documentation?

Tags: python, api, selenium, webdriver

Where can I find the "API docs" for the Python Bindings for Selenium WebDriver?

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings

Comment: Thanks, but you could have just posted a link to it.

Comment: And you should provide a sentence of introduction and a link to "WebDriver" (whatever that is).

Comment: @Keith: There is no link to it. Hence the whole point of posting it here.

Comment: @ThomasH: I will add that now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The official documentation is available on the <strike>[Selenium Google Page](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html)</strike>[Selenium official documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html). The ReadTheDocs version is not official and not maintained by the Selenium project so *may* or *may not* be in date

Comment: Link is updated now.

Answer (score 24):

The API docs for the Webdriver Python bindings are now at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ **(Unofficial)**

Comment: ReadTheDocs version is not official and is not maintained by the Selenium project.

Comment: The link [http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/] is not working

Answer (score 11):

Just thought I share this in case it can come in handy.

```
add_cookie
==========
Adds a cookie to your current session.
        Args:
            cookie_dict: A dictionary object, with the desired cookie name as the key, and
            the value being the desired contents.
        Usage:
            driver.add_cookie({'foo': 'bar',})


back
====
Goes one step backward in the browser history.
        Usage:
            driver.back()


capabilities
============
dict() -> new empty dictionary
dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
    (key, value) pairs
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
    in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)

close
=====
Closes the current window.
        Usage:
            driver.close()


command_executor
================
A connection with the Remote WebDriver server.

    Communicates with the server using the WebDriver wire protocol:
    http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol


create_web_element
==================
Creates a web element with the specified element_id.

current_url
===========
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

current_window_handle
=====================
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

delete_all_cookies
==================
Delete all cookies in the scope of the session.
        Usage:
            driver.delete_all_cookies()


delete_cookie
=============
Deletes a single cookie with the given name.
        Usage:
            driver.delete_cookie('my_cookie')


error_handler
=============
Handles errors returned by the WebDriver server.

execute
=======
Sends a command to be executed by a command.CommandExecutor.
        Args:
          driver_command: The name of the command to execute as a string.
          params: A dictionary of named parameters to send with the command.
        Returns:
          The command's JSON response loaded into a dictionary object.


execute_async_script
====================
Asynchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.
        Args:
            script: The JavaScript to execute.
            args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
        Usage:
            driver.execute_async_script('document.title')


execute_script
==============
Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.
        Args:
            script: The JavaScript to execute.
            *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
        Usage:
            driver.execute_script('document.title')


find_element
============
'Private' method used by the find_element_by_* methods.
        Usage:
            Use the corresponding find_element_by_* instead of this.


find_element_by_class_name
==========================
Finds an element by class name.
        Args:
            name: The class name of the element to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')


find_element_by_css_selector
============================
Finds an element by css selector.
        Args:
            css_selector: The css selector to use when finding elements.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')


find_element_by_id
==================
Finds an element by id.
        Args:
            id_: The id of the element to be found.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_id('foo')


find_element_by_link_text
=========================
Finds an element by link text.
        Args:
            link_text: The text of the element to be found.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')


find_element_by_name
====================
Finds an element by name.
        Args:
            name: The name of the element to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_name('foo')


find_element_by_partial_link_text
=================================
Finds an element by a partial match of its link text.
        Args:
            link_text: The text of the element to partially match on.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign')


find_element_by_tag_name
========================
Finds an element by tag name.
        Args:
            name: The tag name of the element to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_tag_name('foo')


find_element_by_xpath
=====================
Finds an element by xpath.
        Args:
            xpath: The xpath locator of the element to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')


find_elements
=============
'Private' method used by the find_elements_by_* methods.
        Usage:
            Use the corresponding find_elements_by_* instead of this.


find_elements_by_class_name
===========================
Finds elements by class name.
        Args:
            name: The class name of the elements to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')


find_elements_by_css_selector
=============================
Finds elements by css selector.
        Args:
            css_selector: The css selector to use when finding elements.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')


find_elements_by_id
===================
Finds multiple elements by id.
        Args:
            id_: The id of the elements to be found.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_id('foo')


find_elements_by_link_text
==========================
Finds elements by link text.
        Args:
            link_text: The text of the elements to be found.
        Usage:
            driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Sign In')


find_elements_by_name
=====================
Finds elements by name.
        Args:
            name: The name of the elements to find.
        Usage:
            driver.find_elements_by_name('foo')


find_elements_by_partial_link_text
==================================
Finds elements by a partial match of their link text.
        Args:
            link_text: The text of the element to partial match on.
        Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign')


find_elements_by_tag_name
=========================
Finds elements by tag name.
        Args:
            name: The tag name the use when finding elements.
        Usage:
            driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('foo')


find_elements_by_xpath
======================
Finds multiple elements by xpath.
        Args:
            xpath: The xpath locator of the elements to be found.
        Usage:
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]")


forward
=======
Goes one step forward in the browser history.
        Usage:
            driver.forward()


get
===
Loads a web page in the current browser session.

get_cookie
==========
Get a single cookie by name. Returns the cookie if found, None if not.
        Usage:
            driver.get_cookie('my_cookie')


get_cookies
===========
Returns a set of dictionaries, corresponding to cookies visible in the 
        current session.
        Usage:
            driver.get_cookies()


get_current_window_handle
=========================
Returns the handle of the current window.
        Usage:
            driver.get_current_window_handle()
        Note: this method has been deprecated. Please use current_window_handle 
            property"


get_page_source
===============
Gets the source of the current page.
        Usage:
            driver.get_page_source()
        Note: 
            This call has been deprecated. Please use page_source property


get_screenshot_as_base64
========================
Gets the screenshot of the current window as a base64 encoded string which 
        is useful in embedded images in HTML.
        Usage:
            driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()


get_screenshot_as_file
======================
Gets the screenshot of the current window. Returns False if there is 
        any IOError, else returns True. Use full paths in your filename.
        Args:
            filename: The full path you wish to save your screenshot to.
        Usage:
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/Screenshots/foo.png')


get_window_handles
==================
Returns the handles of all windows within the current session.
        Usage:
            driver.get_window_handles()
        Note: this method has been deprecated. Please use window_handles
            property


implicitly_wait
===============
Sets a sticky timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found, 
        or a command to complete. This method only needs to be called one time per session.
        Args:
            time_to_wait: Amount of time to wait
        Usage:
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)


name
====
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

page_source
===========
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

quit
====
Quits the driver and closes every associated window.
        Usage:
            driver.quit()


refresh
=======
Refreshes the current page.
        Usage:
            driver.refresh()


session_id
==========
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

set_script_timeout
==================
Set the amount of time that the script should wait before throwing an
           error.
        Args:
            time_to_wait: The amount of time to wait
        Usage:
            driver.set_script_timeout(30)


start_client
============
Called before starting a new session. This method may be overridden 
        to define custom startup behavior.

start_session
=============
Creates a new session with the desired capabilities.
        Args:
          browser_name: The name of the browser to request.
          version: Which browser version to request.
          platform: Which platform to request the browser on.
          javascript_enabled: Whether the new session should support JavaScript.
          browser_profile: A browser profile directory as a Base64-encoded
              zip file.  Only used if Firefox is requested.


stop_client
===========
Called after executing a quit command. This method may be overridden 
        to define custom shutdown behavior.

switch_to_active_element
========================
Returns the element with focus, or BODY if nothing has focus.
        Usage:
            driver.switch_to_active_element()


switch_to_alert
===============
Switches focus to an alert on the page.
        Usage:
            driver.switch_to_alert()


switch_to_default_content
=========================
Switch focus to the default frame.
        Usage:
            driver.switch_to_default_content()


switch_to_frame
===============
Switches focus to the specified frame, by index or name.
        Args:
            index_or_name: The name of the window to switch to, or 
            an integer representing the index to switch to.
        Usage:
            driver.switch_to_frame('frame_name')
            driver.switch_to_frame(1)


switch_to_window
================
Switches focus to the specified window.
        Args:
            window_name: The name of the window to switch to.
        Usage:
            driver.switch_to_window('main')


title
=====
unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object

Create a new Unicode object from the given encoded string.
encoding defaults to the current default string encoding.
errors can be 'strict', 'replace' or 'ignore' and defaults to 'strict'.

window_handles
==============
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

Comment: +1 There really doesn't seem to be an approachable API documentation; in the linked WebDriver page they just say "import and invoke dir(<modulename>) to find out" :-).

Comment: +1 I like it :). Even it's in source code,  it should be on internet (even just for googling;)).

Answer (score -5):

While it is nice when developers put up a searchable api docs online,
it is common practise in python to just generate it yourself from source code
when you need it, using a doc generator like epydoc or similar.

Comment: You might be giving good advice, but you aren't helping with SO question i.e documentation link.